# PDF files Stitching with cover page and disclaimer pages

Tags: pdf

The possibility to stitch multiple PDF files as one merged PDF file.

We need to stitch multiple PDF financial Report as a single merged PDF file( One PDF report package).

The first page of each report is the cover page, then follows by report body, and last

one or more pages contain disclaimer info. The table content on the cover page is

different for each of the seperated Reports before stiting; and the disclaimers info is also some difference from each other.

What we want to do is that the merged PDF package after stitching should contains

one cover page with a new table content info, such as the page numbers for each section

in this stitched PDF report package; and one set of combined disclosures info on the last

one or several pages should covered all disclaimer info, no missing and no repeating any

of the disclaimer info from the speared reports before stitching.

The report bodies themselves should be concatenated together in the between of the cover

page and first disclaimer pager after merged PDF package.

Comment: I'm looking for something similar myself for .net, Anyone know which Adobe product supports this

Answer (score 2):

If you are using either Java or C#, you can probably use the iText PDF library. In particular, see the 'addPage()' method of the PdfCopy class:

[PdfCopy Class addPage method](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfCopy.html#addPage%28com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1):

If commercial products are an option for you, and you are targeting Windows, you could use [Amyuni PDF Creator ActiveX](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreatoractivex) (C++, Delphi, VB, ASP Classic, etc) or [Amyuni PDF Converter .Net](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features.html) (C#, VB.NET etc) for this task, specifically the `Append` method. You can get customer support during evaluation period.

From the [documentation](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_ACTIVE_X/Using_the_PDF_Creator_Control/Methods/Document_Handling/Append_Method.htm):

> Append Method
>
> The Append method can be used to append or concatenate a PDF file to
> the current document. Syntax:
>
> - C++: HRESULT Append ([in] BSTR FileName,[in] BSTR Password)
> - C#: void Append (string fileName, string password)
> - VB: Sub Append (FileName As String, Password As String)

You may also need to use [DeletePage](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_ACTIVE_X/Using_the_PDF_Creator_Control/Methods/Page_Handling/DeletePage_Method.htm) and [Merge](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Developer_Documentation.htm) methods. Merge method is for drawing the content of a PDF file on top of another PDF file.

*Usual disclaimer applies.*